# Excel VBA Group Variables together and perform For Each in the group

Tags: arrays, excel, foreach, grouping, vba

I am writing a code that encompasses a group of about 11 Arrays. I want to perform the same action on the respective element in each array. I am wondering if there is a way to group the arrays together and run a For Each on the group. Here is a very trivial example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Array1 = ("A", "", "C")
Array2 = ("", "B", "C")
Array3 = ("","","C")
'Is there a way to group these arrays by say Group(Array1,Array2,Array3) 
'Or something like that to then do the following

For Each (Array in Group)
For i = 1 To 3 ' Position in Array
If ((Array in Group)) (i) = "" Then ' Test each position in the array
((Array in Group)) (i) = 1
End If
Next
Next
```

This is a very trivial example to illustrate the point I am trying to make. I just want to know if I can group the Arrays so that I can loop through in a For Each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
group = array(array1, array2, array3)
```

then you can use for each. Although it's more efficient to loop using an index variable rather than for each.